# Able to access `$scope` and `this` using controller as syntax. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm building an Angular controller using `controller as` syntax:

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl as myCtrl">
  <p>accessed via scope resolution: {{ foo }} </p>
  <p>accessed via controller resolution: {{ myCtrl.foo }}</p>
</body>
```

In the controller I have this:

```
myApp.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  this.foo = 'Controller\'s foo';
  $scope.foo = '$scope\'s foo';
});
```

The code above works and prints bot `controller's foo` and `$scope's foo`.

- Why?
- Is this just a case of "unspecified behavior"?
- Is there ever a time when you would want to use both in the real world?

Comment: From the documentation: The controller instance can be published into a scope property by specifying ng-controller="as propertyName". So propertyName.foo is referring to $scope.foo

Comment: Additionally, there are times when you'll want to inject $scope if you have event listeners (`$scope.$on()`) or need to explicitly watch (`$scope.$watch()`) a variable or function return value, even when using 'controller as' syntax. I found [this article very helpful](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) in explaining why.

Comment: Please refer below link, in-detail explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good in details explanation at

http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

Hope this helps !